# Laravel VUEJS how to pass value of v-model

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

why cant I pass the value of v-model product_id?, So I have a method that when the select menu is changed it will run and will get the product price from the database.
Here is the select menu:

```
<tr v-for="(form, index) in addForms">
        <td class="text-xs-left">
             <select @change="getPrice()" v-model="form.product_id" class="form-control">
                   <option disabled>Select Product</option>
                   <option v-for="product in products" :value="product.product_id">{{product.product_name}}</option>
             </select>
        </td>
```

And this is where the product_price is supposed to show up

```
<td class="text-xs-left">                       
       <select v-model="form.product_price" class="form-control">
             <option v-for="product in producti" :value="product.price">{{product.price}}</option>
       </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

And this is the method used to get the price:

```
getPrice: function(){
     axios.get('/api/productd',{
     params: {
              product_id: this.addForms.product_id
             }
             }).then(function(response){
              this.producti = response.data;
             }.bind(this));
     }
```

If it will help here's the function that i used to create a new row when the cannabis(lol) button is pressed:

```
addForm(){
    this.addForms.push({
        recipient: '',
        supplier_id: '',
        to_address: '',
        order_quantity: '',
        product_price: 0,
        product_id: 0,
        product_total: ''
      });
}
```

Everything works, as when I try to set the `product_id:100(inside the params)` it will fetch the product_price of the product with an id of 100`(product_id:100)`, I think the problem is on how i get the product_id from addForms

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to change `@change="getPrice()"` to `@change="getPrice"` and method from `getPrice: function(){` to `getPrice(e) {` and console log `e`

Comment: Changed it, and it prints the event in the console. I've also tried checking VUE in the developers tab, the object[0](which is row 1,2...so on) contains the product_id of the product. However the function getPrice is still unable to get the product_id of row 1,etc.

Comment: What if I increment everytime the button to add row is pressed? and use that incremented value to this.addForms[incrementedvalue].product_id?

Comment: Can't you get the value form the object logged? Otherwise you can try watching the `form.product_price` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property